# Google Play Store installs/uninstalls/sales API

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to find an API to fetch the number of installs, uninstalls and sales for my app on Google Play Store, with filtering by date, but I haven't found anything like that, only for iOS. Does anybody know one?